# AWS AD connector to on premise AD failed

Tags: active-directory, aws-directory-service, directory-services

I am attempting to setup AWS AD Connector to our on-premise Active Directory by following Amazon document "AD Connector Prerequisites".

The status is Failed with the following error.

Connectivity issues detected: DNS unavailable (TCP port 53) for IP: ..., Please ensure that the listed ports are available and retry the operation.

I am assured the port is opened as I could see that the traffics are allowed on firewall.

Below is the connectivity test from the subnet:

```
C:\temp\DirectoryServicePortTest>DirectoryServicePortTest.exe -d domain.local -i
p x.x.x.x -tcp "53,88,389,636" -udp "53,88,389,636"
Testing forest functional level.
Forest Functional Level = Windows2003Forest : PASSED

Testing domain functional level.
Domain Functional Level = Windows2003Domain : PASSED

Testing TCP ports to x.x.x.x:
Checking TCP port 53: PASSED
Checking TCP port 88: PASSED
Checking TCP port 389: PASSED
Checking TCP port 636: FAILED

Testing UDP ports to x.x.x.x:
Checking UDP port 53: PASSED
Checking UDP port 88: PASSED
Checking UDP port 389: PASSED
Checking UDP port 636: PASSED

Press <enter> to continue.
```

Any ideas about that?

Comment: Can you please provide the reference of complexity level of the password which is required?
I am getting the same issue 'connectivity issue detected" Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update for whoever interested:
The cause of the problem is just that user password don't satisfy the complexity requirement. It will be much helpful if the Amazon messages could be more meaningful.